# Only allow numbers as user input values to Application.InputBox for CommandButton1_Click()

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with an annoyning possibility, that users can insert decimal/fraction values although only whole numbers should be allowed. 
I've tried to use KeyAscii (48-57) to check if the users enter numbers. However, I cannot get it to work and neither with some other functions. 
The user should not be able to insert anything else than numeric values (from 0 to 9 and up to 99). This applies to "rowNum" in my attached code. 
I have everyhting else in control but I can't get my VBA to work for decimal/fraction values inserted by users after pressing the CommandButton_Click(). 
I've tried now for many hours to find a solution without success. All help appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowNum As Variant
Dim x As Variant
On Error Resume Next

rowNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the row from where you want to add new empty rows downwards:", _
                                    Title:="Need to add new empty rows?", Type:=1)

                If (VarType(rowNum) = vbBoolean) And (rowNum = False) Then
                MsgBox "You canceled the event!", vbExclamation, "No Input!"

                ElseIf rowNum = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Smallest allowed row number is 7!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                ElseIf rowNum < 0 Then
                MsgBox "Negative values are not allowed!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                ElseIf rowNum < 7 Then 
        MsgBox "Smallest allowed row number is 7!!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

        ElseIf rowNum > 99 Then 
        MsgBox "Highest allowed row number is 99!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                              End If
                              If rowNum < 7 Or rowNum > 99 Then End



x = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please insert the amount of empty rows that you need:", _
                            Title:="Amount of new rows?", Type:=1)


                If (VarType(x) = vbBoolean) And (x = False) Then
                MsgBox "You canceled the event!", vbExclamation, "No Input!"

                ElseIf x = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Smallest amount of new rows is 2!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                ElseIf x < 2 Then
                MsgBox "Smallest amount of new rows is 2!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                ElseIf x > 10 Then
                MsgBox "Highest amount of new rows is 10!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"

                              End If
                              If x < 2 Or x > 10 Then End

Rows(rowNum & ":" & rowNum + x - 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: `isnumeric` can check for numeric values?

Comment: Hello Nathan, unfortunately I can't get isnumeric to work because it seems to allow commas and points (for instance 8,7 or 12.2) as numbers as well. The user should only be able to input values between 0 and 9 (without any commas or points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding another  elseif clause

```
ElseIf x <> Int(x) Then
       MsgBox "Fraction number is not  allowed", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input!"


End if
```

may solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

declaring as a variant is the issue as that will accept any input type. If you instead declare x and RowNum as integers you will avoid this issue.

Doing this will round any decimals to whole numbers, and text will hit an error (Type 13: Mismatch) This can be handled in an error handler or skipped

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have declared x and rowNum as variants because of other issues (user selects cancel instead of input value). However, the "ElseIf x <> Int(x) Then" fixed my problem.

Comment: No worries, I did try doing what Ahmed suggested but mine was saying I was inputting a string, which is why i settled on this one